# How to embed XMP metadata into multi-pages PDF/A3 file?

Tags: java, itext, metadata, xmp, pdfa

I am currently working on a project, which is a TIFF to PDF format converter. It takes a sequence of scanned collection TIFF files, and transforms them to a single multi-pages PDF/A3 file. I finished this part of project, and focus on metadata handling problems right now.

My boss wants me embedding metadata of each TIFF into each corresponding page of PDF file. I have no idea how to do that. According to my research on PDF/A metadata structure, it seems like there should be only one xmp file in PDF, and if I want to embed certain page of matadata, I have to give out a pointer that points it to where I want it be. In my project, the basic idea I thought so far is, I should extract metadata from each TIFF file (I know how to do this step), combine and transform all of these into the PDF file. I tried to use iText, but it seems do not support doing this way.

Does anyone know how to do that? Is there a open tool to do this way? My primary language is Java.

Thanks all!!!

Comment: *"According to my research on PDF/A metadata structure, it seems like there should be only one xmp file in PDF"* - there often only is one metadata stream which is the one associated with the document as a whole. There can be more, though, see my comment to Samuel's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in your research.

Well, mostly, because it is important to make the distinction between the metadata belonging to the pdf-document as a whole, and meta-data belonging to the TIFF-image.
The first is indeed limited to a single instance per pdf.
The second is indepedent of the pdf meta-data, but can be added as a file-attachment, this is allowed by the PDF/A-3 standard.
Both types are independent of any page, so in that sense, your Boss' request reveals a lack of knowledge about pdf's as a format.

You could however put a link annotation on each Tiff that points towards its metada, optionally stored in a second pdf file, giving the illusion that the data is somehow present on the page.

Now, I must respectfully disagree with your statement that iText does not provide you with the tools to deal with this problem. [Chapter 7 of the iText7 Jumpstart tutoria](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-7-creating-pdfua-and-pdfa-documents)l deals with the creation of PDF/A-X, including embedding files. PDF/A-3 is the third example.

As for the link annotations, they're possible with some knowledge of the Pdf-spec (Embedded Go-To Actions) and the low-level manipulation methods of iText. I don't have a ready example right now, but I'll see if I can brew something and add it to this answer later.

EDIT:
Well, this is disappointing, neither Foxit nor Adobe's readers support embedded go-to actions. Still, in case you are interested, below is the code I used to create a PDF/A-3 compliant document using iText7, adding metadata as a seperate Pdf.

```
public static String INTENT = "src/test/resources/StackOverflow/EmbeddedLinking/sRGB_CS_profile.icm";
public static String IMG = "src/test/resources/StackOverflow/EmbeddedLinking/itis.jpg";
public static String META = "target/output/StackOverflow/EmbeddedLinking/metadata.pdf";
public static String DEST = "target/output/StackOverFlow/EmbeddedLinking/embeddedMetaData.pdf";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, java.io.IOException {
    File file = new File(DEST);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    new EmbeddedLinking().createPdf(META);
    new EmbeddedLinking().createPdfWithEmbeddedFile(DEST,META,IMG,INTENT);
}

public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException{
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
    //Put some data here
    doc.add(new Paragraph("This is the metadata"));
    doc.add(new Paragraph("The Cake is Lie"));
    doc.add(new Paragraph("42"));
    doc.add(new Paragraph("The Spice must flow"));
    doc.close();
}

public void createPdfWithEmbeddedFile(String dest, String embeddedPath, String imgPath, String intent) throws java.io.IOException {
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
    PdfOutputIntent outputIntent = new PdfOutputIntent("Custom", "","http://www.color.org", "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", new FileInputStream(intent));
    PdfADocument pdfADoc = new PdfADocument(writer, PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_3A,outputIntent);

    //Setting some required parameters
    pdfADoc.setTagged();
    pdfADoc.getCatalog().setLang(new PdfString("en-US"));
    pdfADoc.getCatalog().setViewerPreferences(
            new PdfViewerPreferences().setDisplayDocTitle(true));
    PdfDocumentInfo info = pdfADoc.getDocumentInfo();
    info.setTitle("iText7 PDF/A-3 Embedded Go-To example");

    //Add attachment
    PdfDictionary parameters = new PdfDictionary();
    parameters.put(PdfName.ModDate, new PdfDate().getPdfObject());
    PdfFileSpec fileSpec = PdfFileSpec.createEmbeddedFileSpec(
            pdfADoc, Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(embeddedPath)), "metadata.pdf",
            "metadata.pdf", new PdfName("application/pdf"), parameters,
            PdfName.Data, false);
    fileSpec.put(new PdfName("AFRelationship"), new PdfName("Data"));
    pdfADoc.addFileAttachment("metadata.pdf", fileSpec);
    PdfArray array = new PdfArray();
    array.add(fileSpec.getPdfObject().getIndirectReference());
    pdfADoc.getCatalog().put(new PdfName("AF"), array);

    //Add Image
    int imagePage = 1; //We know the image will end up on the first page since it's the only thing we add to the document
    Document doc = new Document(pdfADoc, PageSize.A4);
    Image img = new Image(ImageDataFactory.create(imgPath));
    doc.add(img);


    //Add link annotation to embedded file
    float pageHeight = PageSize.A4.getHeight();
    float imageWidth = img.getImageWidth();
    float imageHeight = img.getImageHeight();
    float x = doc.getLeftMargin();
    float y = pageHeight - doc.getTopMargin() - imageHeight;
    Rectangle linkAnnotationPosition = new Rectangle(x,y,imageWidth,imageHeight);

    PdfLinkAnnotation linkAnnotation = new PdfLinkAnnotation(linkAnnotationPosition);
    //Setup the Embedded GoTO action
    PdfExplicitDestination explicitDestination = PdfExplicitDestination.createFit(imagePage);//Destination in the target file
    PdfTargetDictionary targetDictionary = PdfTargetDictionary.createChildTarget("metadata.pdf"); //Target embedded file
    PdfAction action = PdfAction.createGoToE(fileSpec,explicitDestination,true,targetDictionary);
    linkAnnotation.setAction(action);
    //PDF/A requires the presence of the F -bit flag array in every dictionary. The print flag needs to be 1, and some other flags 0.
    //See the spec for details and options, but the bit pattern represented by the integer 4 suffices for conformance to PDF/A-3
    int fBitArray = 4;
    linkAnnotation.put(PdfName.F,new PdfNumber(fBitArray));
    //Add annotation to page
    pdfADoc.getPage(imagePage).addAnnotation(linkAnnotation);

    //Close document
    doc.close();
}
```

Comment: *"the metadata belonging to the pdf-file [...] is indeed limited to a single instance per pdf."* - Is it? According to ISO 32000-1 *any PDF stream or dictionary may have metadata attached to it* (section 14.3.2), and I didn't find a restriction to this in ISO 19005-3, on the contrary it requires *all metadata streams present in the PDF shall conform to the XMP Specification* (section 6.6.2.1) which implies that there may be multiple metadata streams. Or did you mean that there may be only a single instance of metadata referring to the document as a whole? Then you are right.

Comment: @mkl the latter, only one instance of metadata belonging to the document as a whole. I'll edit the answer, since the wording is indeed a bit ambiguous .